# Android- Going back to Previous Activity with different Intent value

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application that has this transition:

```
 A -> B -> C -> D-> C
```

Upon entering `C` , i have to check a flag. Then I have to pass it as intent (let us say `intentX = false`) to `D`. After doing something in `D` , it will then go back to `C` after pressing a button.
What i did was just pass again the `intentX` with value true, then startActivity C again. 
So what happen is that it created another Activity C.

What i want to happen is that i will not have to start a new Activity C, but use the previous C by just calling `super.onBackPressed()`. But I cannot pass the new value of the `intentX`. Is there other way, to achieve what i want. I might have missed some.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you want is `startActivityForResult()`. When you go from `C` to `D`, instead of using `startActivity()` use instead `startActivityForResult()`. Then when you want to return from `D` to `C` you use `setResult()` which can include an `Intent` object with `extras` to pass back to `C`.

I don't recommend doing this in `onBackPressed()` if you don't *have* to because this will not be what the user expects. Instead, you should return with this data with an event such as a `Button` click.

So, in `C` you will do something like

```
 Intent i = new Intent(new Intent(C.this, D.class);
 startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

then in `D` when you are ready to return

```
 Intent i = new Intent();
 i.putExtra();  // insert your extras here
 setResult(0, i);
```

then when you return to `C` you will enter this method ([taken from the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html))

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
         Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             // A contact was picked.  Here we will just display it
             // to the user.
             startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, data));

             /* 
                can also get the extra sent back through data
                using data.getStringExtra("someKey"); 
                assuming the extra was a String
             */

         }
```

Comment: oh, i'll have to try again this one. i must have use it the wrong way before.

Comment: That's possible, its easy to get confused on it at first until you understand how it works. This should be enough to get you started but there is also a decent example in the docs that I linked to and tutorials and examples on The Google and SO

Comment: When you "are ready to return" after setting the result - what function should be called? Should I call `finish()`?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber that depends. Usually, yes, as in if you put the return code in an `onClick()` event. If it is in `onBackPressed()` then you just call `super.onBackPressed()` since that takes it through the `finish()` process so no need to call it there.

Answer (score 1):

There are some cases where startActivityForResult is not really needed or it is not practical to change all startActivity calls for startActivityForResult.

If the simple case of just starting a previous activity 'again' is needed, my recommendation is: Use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag.

Quoting a brief [description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP):

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.
>
> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D.
>   If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the
>   component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive
>   the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

So this example

```
   // From ActivityD
   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // The flag we wanted
   intent.putExtra(ActivityB.SOME_EXTRA_THAT_I_NEED_CHANGED, SomeValue); // Example of changing the intent to get something new..
   startActivity(intent);
```

Where you will get that new intent is defined by which launch mode and which flags where used to start it (in this case our ActivityB).

> The currently running instance of activity B in the above example will
>   either receive the new intent you are starting here in its
>   onNewIntent() method, or be itself finished and restarted with the new
>   intent. If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the
>   default) and you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same
>   intent, then it will be finished and re-created; for all other launch
>   modes or if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be
>   delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent().