# Go back to activity with new variable

Tags: android

Here is what I want:

1. In Activity No.1. some variables receive values (variable A and B)
2. Here the user launches Activity No.2. and sets a variable (variable C)
3. User presses a button that takes him back to Activity No.1.
4. Activity No.1. has now the value of all the three variables.

I can pass the variables to Activity No.2. with an intent and retrieve them there using a Bundle. But is it an appropriate way to open Activity No.1. by using basically the same lines that I used to start Activity No.2?

In Activity No.1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityNo2.class);
intent.putExtra("date", date);
intent.putExtra("filename", filename);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity No.2:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String date = bundle.getString("date");
String filename = bundle.getString("filename");
String variableC = "somevalue";
```

What's the best way to return to Activity No.1. with the new variable?

Comment: Do you use the variables in activity 2 that you have passed it?

Comment: No, I don't. I passed it to have it when I go back.

Comment: Then why not use `startActivityForResult()` to start `Activity 2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing would work but there is a better way. The way you are doing it is just creating more possible errors. And Android provides a solution for this type of occasion.

You can use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivityForResult) to go to `Activity 2`. This will allow you to send a result back to `Activity 1` with variable C.

As long as you have given the variables the correct scope in `Activity 1` they will still be there when you return to `onActivityResult()`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243515/android-going-back-to-previous-activity-with-different-intent-value/18243541#18243541) gives a little more explanation on how to use it.

Comment: I had a hunch that this would be the solution, just wasn't sure about it then I got distracted by the world of startActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a variable in class A (Activity 1), get an instance of class A(from class B[this is the singleton design pattern]) and set the value of that variable via a setMethod?