# switching activities with common view, difference between onResume and onActivityResult

Tags: java, android

I have application with several activities with common `View`s (a few `Buttons` and a `TextView`). I've  created the common `View` and handled the actions in abstract class that `extends Activity` and all my activities extends my abstract class.

My problem was when I switched between activities and changed a text on a `Button`. For example, when I pressed "back" button the previous `Activity` didn't have the "updated" text on the `Button`. I added in my abstract class `onActivityResult()` method and changed in all activities to open new activity from startActivity to startActivityForResult. Now it's working fine but I found out that there's also `onResume()` method that can handle my first problem.

So my question is: what is better? or even more accurate: what is the right way to handle my problem?
thanks

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243515/android-going-back-to-previous-activity-with-different-intent-value/18243541#18243541

Comment: but in my case I don't have a "specific related data" to pass from the activity. my button is the log in button, which opens log in activity if no user logged in or do log out if the user is logged in, if the answer is still the same, why would we ever need then the onResume method?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons for `onResume()`. But it is called directly after `onCreate()` **and** when returning to the Activity unless `onActivityResult()` is called. I don't understand your exact scenario so I can't really give you the answer. Data doesn't need to be sent back to use it and I didn't know your specific case which is why I didn't close as a dupe but linked to it instead.

Comment: in order to know what to write on the button (Login or Logout) I use a method check() which I call every time I enter activity (the parse user is defined on abstract class so in all activities) and I don't send "special" data from activity X to activity Y, so I'm still confused on what method is more "programmatic right" way to use?

Comment: Then calling `check()` in `onResume()` would be what you want

Comment: so it is using onResume() if no specific data needed to transfer from activity X to activity Y and if needed then onActivityResult(), thank you very much!

Comment: Basically, yes. I can try to write up an answer in a bit to clarify things a little better if you'd like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't needing to return any data and the text that the `Button` should have is obtained in a function called every time the `Activity` opens, simply using `onResume()` will suffice.

`onResume()` is called each time the the `Activity` runs, after `onCreate()` runs, but it is also called each time the `Activity` comes to the foreground (say, by hitting the back button from the activity in front of it).

> what is the right way to handle my problem?

So, while you could use either, there is no need here for `startActivityForResult()`. It would just add unnecessary code and overhead (even though I doubt your users would see a difference). Just add the method which checks for the text that the button needs to `onResume()`.

[onResume() Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume())

When you do want to return data from a called activity and take specific action depending on that data, [I've got an example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243515/android-going-back-to-previous-activity-with-different-intent-value/18243541#18243541)