# Passing a variable, updating it, then sending updated variable to original activity

Tags: android, variables, android-intent, android-activity, int

So I have been using the getIntent method to send my original int value, set to 10, to a second class.

```
Intent webClick = new Intent(this, WebsearchIAP.class);
webClick.putExtra("cred", cred);
startActivity(webClick);
```

Then, I update the variable by subtracting 1 from it.

```
Intent get = getIntent();
int cred = get.getIntExtra("cred", 10);

public void buyClick(View view) {
    sCredits.setText(cred - 1);
}
```

Then, I want to send it back to my MainActivity, by doing this.

```
public void backClick(View view) {
    Intent close = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    close.putExtra("cred", cred);
    startActivity(close);
}
```

Once back in my MainActivity, this is what I would like to do.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent close = getIntent();
    int cred = get.getIntExtra("cred", [VALUE OF CRED IN PREVIOUS ACTIVITY]);
}
```

My problem is the getIntent method requires the numerical value of "cred", which would be no big deal if I was using the method only once, but I want to use it every time this app resumes the main screen, hence the call to onResume. So, how do I set my app to take the value of "cred" in the previous activity, no matter what it may be, in one method?

Comment: I'm hesitant to mark as a dupe because I think you might be asking multiple questions here but, you should be using [startActivityForResult](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243515/android-going-back-to-previous-activity-with-different-intent-value/18243541#18243541)

Comment: I didn't get you. Do you want cred to be accessed in all activities? Or you want to just pass the variable to other activity and receive it back after processing?

Comment: You can also create an interface in second Activity and implement it in first Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `SharedPreferences`. It is commonly used for storing app preferences and is shared in the application.

Firstly, get your SharedPreferences in your activity:

```
private SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("foo", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and then set and put value like this:

```
int cred = sp.getInt("CRED", 10);        // Put this statement in onResume
sp.edit().putInt("CRED", cred).apply();
```

You can get offical docs for SharedPferences [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is a best way for doing this. Send an intent to second activity from first using `startActivityForResult()`instead of `startActivity()`. Then from second Activity use `setResult()` to send the value back to the first Activity. Override `onActivityResult()` in first activity to get the updated value.
Example:

```
 //First Activity
 Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),secondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("cred",cred);
 startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_CODE);

 //second Activity
 Intent i=getIntent();
 cred=i.getIntExtra("cred",10);
 //....Update your values
 Intent sendBack=new Intent();
 sendBack.putExtra("cred",cred);
 setResult(RESULT_CODE,sendBack);

 //First Activity
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data)
 {
 if(resCode==RESULT_CODE)
 cred=data.getIntExtra("cred",10);
 }
 //RESULT_CODE is a integer to be kept constant for a type of result.
```