# Get users text and display it in a text view in a different class

Tags: java, android

I am creating a review page. When user clicks on the review stars in ClassOne.java it takes them to a different activity which is ClassTwo.java. When user writes their review and clicks on submit I want their review to go back to ClassOne.java and display it in the TextView under Reviews section. I have sumbit button in ClassTwo.java not shown in the image. This is what i have so far but I keep getting this error, "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'on a null object reference". How can i fix this problem?

[ClassOne.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuLd0.png)
[ClassTwo.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTvYv.png)
`ClassTwo.java`

`public class ClassTwo extends Activity{`

```
private TextView reviewDisplay;
private Button submitButton;
private EditText usersReview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.rating_click);

submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Editable editTextReview = usersReview.getText();
            reviewDisplay.setText(editTextReview);
            Intent intent = new Intent(ClassTwo.this, ClassOne.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You'll also want to see [Going back to previous Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243515/android-going-back-to-previous-activity-with-different-intent-value/18243541#18243541)

Comment: And [How do I pass data between Activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)